# Java runtime jar missing

Tags: java

I am new to java,

I am trying to send email from my java class, I tried the code in windows, it has some problem initially. After I put mail-1.4.jar into `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext` then it runs fine.

I just moved this to my server(AWS), put this java file in a folder and trying to run this class. I put mail-1.4.jar in path `/opt/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/ext`

My java class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Mail {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            URISyntaxException, AddressException, MessagingException {
        String BODY = "\n\n Regards Admin.";
        String SUBJECT = "SUBJECT";
        String TO = "fg@gddgh.com";

        final String FROM = "no-reply@dfh.com";
        final String SMTP_USERNAME = "SMTP_USERNAME";
        final String SMTP_PASSWORD = "SMTP_PASSWORD";
        final String HOST = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";

        String message = "Email successfully sent";

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(TO));
            msg.setSubject(SUBJECT);
            msg.setContent(BODY, "text/plain");

            Transport transport = session.getTransport();
            try {
                transport.connect(HOST, SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);
                transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
                System.out.println(message);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                message = "Email not sent to the given ID";
                System.out.println(message);
            } finally {
                transport.close();
            }

    }
}
```

It compiles well when executing command as `javac Mail.java`, but unable to run this class . I got the following exception, while executing `java Mail`

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Address
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Comment: Which web container are you using on AWS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not including the jar to openJdk.

Try to add the jar to your openJdk `pathToOpenJdk/jre/lib/ext` folder. It should works.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have done it well in your local environment: You installed the JavaMail into the JDK extension directory (`jre/lib/ext`). So you have to save it to the same directory in the AWS environment.

Not all libraries in the `jre/lib` directory are loaded systematically, but those in the `jre/lib/ext` are.

See [Oracle's Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html):

> The JRE consists of those directories within the highlighted box in the diagram. Whether your JRE is stand-alone or part of the JDK software, any JAR file in the lib/ext of the JRE directory is automatically treated by the runtime environment as an extension.

Comment: After included in jre/lib/ext  also no luck. its not working.

Comment: @Clara Have you restarted the JVM after including the library?

Comment: Can you help me on how to restart the JVM, I searched lot but confused a lot about possible of restart the JVM.

Comment: Sorry, no. It depends on the environment. You have to search documentation on **managing the AWS server**.